# What does 쫌 mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, slang

I saw the following sticker in one of the shops:

[image: 쫌 sticker]

I tried looking it up on Naver Dict but there were no results (just 2 example sentences). So what does 쫌 mean? If possible, example sentences in which 쫌 is used would also be of great help!

Comment: It is an informal abbreviation of "조금".

Answer (score 4):

"쫌!" by itself is similar to "Oh *pleeeaaase*!!" - it's an expression of exasperation at whatever the other side is doing (or not doing).  It's also rather informal.

"아 쫌!" is also commonly used.

Answer (score 3):

쫌 is an informal abbreviation of '조금'. A more standard abbreviation of 조금 is 좀, and both of them have the same meaning.

[좀](https://stdict.korean.go.kr/search/searchView.do?word_no=301011&searchKeywordTo=3) itself has no specific meaning. Here is a list of the possible meanings of 좀:

> 1. An abbreviation of 조금
> 2. A word that is inserted to make polite a request or asking.
> 3. An extreme extent.
> 4. *How much* (in an interrogative sentence).

Its meaning depends on the context, but I guess 쫌 in your picture has the second meaning. Here are possible example sentences:

> "좀 그만 해!"
>
> *"Stop it, please!"*

좀 in this sentence makes a request (for stopping something) more politely. Note that, however, "좀 그만 해" is still less formal than another form of request like "그만 좀 해 주시겠습니까?"

Here is another example:

> "아 제발 좀 당첨되었으면!" 복권을 사고 나서 외쳤다.
>
> *"Ah, please, I wish I win the lottery!" I shouted after buying a lottery.*

The speaker in the sentence asks their luck (to heaven or the law of probability, or something like that), and 좀 in this sentence corresponds to 'please.'